# In TypeScript 5, how to use a const generic key to create object with that key

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a dynamic object-builder thing in TypeScript 5.x. Boiling down my problem to the smallest possible demonstration, I would like to create a function similar to this:

```
function testFunction<const Key extends string>(key: Key): Record<Key, "wow"> {
  return { [key]: "wow" };
}
```

However this gives me the following error under `return`:

`TS2322: Type { [x: string]: string; } is not assignable to type Record<Key, "wow">`.

Ideally, what I would like to achieve is to have this function act like this:

```
// const result: { "test": "wow" }
const result = testFunction("test");
```

Importantly `result` should not be `{ [p: string]: "wow }`, because I used const everywhere.

I'm not sure where I need to change things, but it seems like something that should be possible. Do I use a different return-type? Do I simply use an `as` for the return?

Any suggestions how I can achieve this?

Comment: This is ms/TS#13948 as mentioned in the linked q/a above.  For now you’ll need an assertion, and be careful because if the key is of a union type your return type will be wrong. There’s a `kv` function in the answer to the other question whose return type is more accurate